# Help with Replacing Strings on Solaris

Tags: search, sed, solaris

I am on a Solaris 8 box that does not support -i option for sed, so I am using the following from a google search on the topic:

```
# find . -name cancel_submit.cgi | while read file; do
> sed 's/ned.dindo.com\/confluence\/display\/CESDT\/CETS+DocTools>DOC Team/wwwin-dev.dindo.com\/Eng\/CntlSvcs\/InfoFrwk\/GblEngWWW\/Public\/index.html>EDCS Team/g' ${file} > ${file}.new
> mv ${file}.new ${file} 
> done
```

This works except it messes up file permissions and group:owner.

How can I retain the original information?

Answer (score 2):

You may use 'cat'. 

`cat ${file}.new > ${file}  && rm ${file}.new`

Comment: Great! Another good alternative. I actually used this one. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

`cp -p` preserves the stuff you want.  Personally I would do this (to imitate `sed -i.bak`):

```
...
cp -p ${file} ${file}.bak
sed 's/..../g' ${file}.bak > ${file}
...
```

You could add `rm ${file}.bak` to the end if desired, in which case you wouldn't technically need the `-p` in the `cp` line above.  But with the above you can do `mv ${file}.bak ${file}` to recover if the replacement goes awry.